# How do you hide other swipe cell actions when swiping the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I have a tableView with native SwipeCell functionality.
When users swipe the cell a little, I have two actions (delete & edit).
When you swipe the cell all the way, it will move the delete button (as expected), the problem is - the background is transparent, so when the delete button is over the edit icon it looks bad.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { [weak self] (action, view, complete) in

        self?.deleteAction(tableView, at: indexPath)
        complete(true)
    }
    if let cgImageX =  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "alarmDelete").cgImage {
        deleteAction.image = ImageWithoutRender(cgImage: cgImageX, scale: UIScreen.main.nativeScale, orientation: .up)
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0)

    let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { [weak self] (action, view, complete) in
        self?.editAction(tableView, at: indexPath)
        complete(true)
    }
    if let editImage =  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "edit").cgImage {
        editAction.image = ImageWithoutRender(cgImage: editImage, scale: UIScreen.main.nativeScale, orientation: .up)
    }
    editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0)
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, editAction])
}
```

Is it possible to hide other actions when moving the cell all the way?
[image: Exibit A]
[image: Exibit B]

Video: https://i.imgur.com/9betbst.mp4

Thanks

Comment: Please post code whatever you have tried.

Comment: Added the function that defines the actions, did not find any way to overcome this problem yet so no other code for this

Comment: `deleteAction` is both a constant and a method? Can you post the code of the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your code as follows to fix your issue.

```
let swipeActionConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, editAction])
swipeActionConfig.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
return swipeActionConfig
```

But, this will prevent first action perform with full swipe, means you can't able to do first action when swipe cell to more after all action display.